# Msysgit git Bash change of behavior on autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, msysgit, git-bash

Up to 1.9.4 git Bash, on hitting tab, would auto-complete up to ambiguity and then let me complete the rest (for branches, tags etc). As of 1.9.5 (version 1.9.5-preview20141217) it will present me with a list of the possible branches/tags etc and let me choose. I much preferred the previous behavior as it saved me screen/logs estate. Is this change revertible somehow or is there a preference I can set ?

Example:

```
MrD@MRSD /c/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/python/wrye-bash (utumno-163-wip)
$ git rebase --interactive --onto dev dev utu # <-- hit tab, boom:
utumno-163-wip           utumno-74-wrap           utumno-liblo-6-support
utumno-195               utumno-cProfile-wip      utumno-parerga
utumno-6                 utumno-liblo-6           utumno-wip
```

What I would like to see is:

```
$ git rebase --interactive --onto dev dev utu # <-- hit tab, ta-dah:
$ git rebase --interactive --onto dev dev utumno-
```

Comment: The bind command of [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/918422/355021) worked for me, I put it in my ~/.profile file.

Comment: @ColinDelhalle: I am on windows so I needed to put `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'` in my `Users\user\.bash_profile` but this did the trick ! Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/904255/bash-completion-in-msysgit-by-single-or-double-tab/918422#918422), putting `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'` in my ~/.profile file did the trick for me.